# Php post form with onkeyup function

Tags: php, jquery, json

**MY FORM:**

```
  <tfoot>
      <form method="post" action="kategoriler.php">
    <tr>
     <th>Select</th>
     <th><input type="text" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" style="width:80px;" placeholder="#"></th>
     <th>Image</th>
     <th><input type="text" name="name" id="name"  class="form-control" style="width:120px;" placeholder="Name"></th>
     <th>Order</th>
     <th><input type="text" name="Visibility" id="Visibility" class="form-control" style="width:120px;" placeholder="Visibility"></th>
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
     </form>
  </tfoot>
```

I want to post this values with json and onkeyup functions how can i send this form values ?

Comment: with onkeyup event ? very bad idea

Comment: whats your idea ? im not good at jquery

Comment: You can use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482939/send-post-form-data-in-json-format-via-ajax-with-jquery-dynamically

Comment: I try ajax but i will use this method on search i want to process with key by key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works add keyup function on all input type in a form

```
$('form input:text').keyup(function(){
      var data = $("form").serialize();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'kategoriler.php',
        data: data,
        dataType:'json',
        type:'POST',
        async:false,
        success: function(data) {
          alert('submitted');
        }
});
```

If you want to add keyup on a specific input type then just replace

```
$('form input:text').keyup(function(){
```

With

```
$('#id').keyup(function(){
```

Comment: how can i get this values on kategoriler.php for example i sent name but i cant take this name other page

Comment: using $_POST...like $all_input_values = $_POST and then $all_input_values['id'] this will get you id value..use same for others

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery ajax for that :

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "kategoriler.php",
              data: {name: $('#name').val() //ETC...},
              success: function (html) {
                 alert('ok');
              }
         });
    });
```

Comment: **onkeyup** op want to submit the form on this event.

Comment: This method will work when i press any button ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this. Provided that you whant to submit the form at any keyup

```
 //trigger form submit
 $(document).keyup(function(){
     $("form").submit();
 });

 //Do what you whant with your form
 $("form").submit(function(){
     //Do something eg. ajax call
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           url: "kategoriler.php",
           data: {name: $('#name').val() //ETC...},
           success: function (html) {
              alert('ok');
           }
      });
 });
```

Comment: I have no submit button i want to process when i press any button ?

Comment: Ok. but isn't that a problem when the user are typing things in your textfield? That would mean that the form getssubmitted for every character. In my opinion it would be more convinient with onChange().

Comment: How can i get this values :)

Comment: trigger submit with change() instead of keyup(). You can get the values in the same maner as described in the other posts